# Reset image modal to prevent previous photo being displayed

Tags: javascript

My modal has an issue where it displays the previous image just before displaying the one just clicked on. I believe that i need to reset the modal on close to prevent this from happening.

Just to clarify, the modal does not slide to the next image. It will need to be closed in order to select the next image.

I have tried resetting the HTML when the modal is closed, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const previews = document.querySelectorAll('.solution-image-container img');
const original = document.querySelector('.full-img');

previews.forEach(preview => {
  preview.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.classList.add('open');
    original.classList.add('open');

    const originalSrc = preview.getAttribute('data-original');
    original.src = originalSrc;
  })
});

modal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    modal.classList.remove('open');
    original.classList.remove('open');
  }

  if (modal.style.opacity === 0) {
    modal.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.solution-image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.solution-image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images-gallery {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

#gallery-img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}


.modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 50;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out;
}

.modal.open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.full-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="solution-image-container">
      <img class="big-img" 
           src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x350" 
           srcset=""
           data-original="https://source.unsplash.com/random/350x350"/>
      <div class="images-gallery">
                  <img
                    id="gallery-img"
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/151x151"
                    alt=""
                    srcset=""
                    data-original="https://source.unsplash.com/random/151x151"
                  />
                  <img
                    id="gallery-img"
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/152x152"
                    alt=""
                    srcset=""
                    data-original="https://source.unsplash.com/random/152x152"
                  />
                  <img
                    id="gallery-img"
                    src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/153x153"
                    alt=""
                    srcset=""
                    data-original="https://source.unsplash.com/random/153x153"
                  />
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
  <img alt="" class="full-img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the src attribute before you add the open class?

Comment: Also great to have a [mcve], but please improve it using images from for example placeholder.com - there is nothing to click on right now

Comment: Also delegate: `document.querySelector('.solution-image-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {  const originalSrc = e.target.getAttribute('data-original');   .... })`